# How do I set up routing to multiple instances of a node.js server on one url?

Tags: node.js, webserver

I have a simple node.js server app built that I'm hoping to test out soon. It's single threaded and works fine without any child processing whatsoever. My problem is that the server box has multiple cores and the simplest way I can think to utilize them is by running multiple instances of the server app. However this would require them all to be on the same domain name and so some sort of request routing is required. I personally don't have much experience with servers in general and don't know if this is a task for node.js to perform or some other less complicated program (or more complicated.) If there is a node.js mechanism to solve this, for example, if one running instance can send incoming requests to the next instance, than how would I detect when this needs to happen? Transversely, if I use some other program how will it manage to detect when it needs to start talking to a new instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js includes built-in support for managing a cluster of instances of your application to take advantage of multiple cores via the [`cluster`](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module.